# Conversion error {0} in Primefaces knob component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I get a error: Conversion error:

**{0}: Conversion error occurred.**

when try to display O value in Primefaces knob component. I already changed input value types to: integer, String, Double and this did not help. I also tried to build a converter, but this component did not use it. I do not have any idea what do with this. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
<p:knob value="#{res.completionValue}" width="50" height="50" disabled="true" converter="knobConverter" />
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter("knobConverter")
public class KnobConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        
        Integer returnValue;
        
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() >0) {
             try{
                 returnValue = (ing) value;
                }
             catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
            }}
                
        return returnValue;
}
 
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        
        if(object != null) {
            return String.valueOf((object));
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's working in the showcase without converter using an integer https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/knob.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the entire class and recreated it (return Integer values, do no use Converter). Now it work correct, generally I do not have any idea what was the reason.